# vue-router 'router-link' not creating link

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to make an admin panel with vue-router. Implemented all the codes but can't check if they are working as I can't click on the  links. The router-link tag is not making the texts clickable.

Here is my Blade File:

```
<div id="app">
  <aside class="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-primary elevation-4">
    <div class="sidebar">
       <nav class="mt-2">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column">
            <li>
                <router-link to="/dashboard"><i class="icon_lifesaver"></i> <span>Dashboard</span>
                </router-link>
            </li>
            <li>
                <router-link to="/category-list"><i class="icon_cog"></i> <span>Category</span></router-link>
            </li>
            <li>
                <router-link to="/post-list"><i class="icon_globe-2"></i> <span>Posts</span></router-link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
    
     </div>

   </aside>
   <div class="content-wrapper">
            <admin-main></admin-main>
        </div>
```

And here is the app.js file

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
Vue.use(VueRouter);

import router from './routes';

Vue.component('admin-main', require('./components/admin/AdminMaster.vue').default);
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    store,
    router
});
```

also, here is the routes.js file where I am defining the routes:

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

import AdminHome from './components/admin/AdminHome.vue'
import CategoryList from './components/admin/category/List.vue'
import AddCategory from './components/admin/category/New.vue'

let routes = [
    {
        path:'/dashboard',
        component:AdminHome
    },
    {
        path:'/category-list',
        component:CategoryList
    },
    {
        path:'/add-category',
        component:AddCategory
    },
    

];


const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
    linkActiveClass: 'active',
    mode: 'history'
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

   
    return next()
});

export default router;
```

Comment: does it work if you remove the i and span tags?

Comment: @lindacom, nope

Comment: If you click F12 in the browser do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: Also do you have a link to the app.js file at the bottom of your blade file?

Comment: @lindacom, thanks buddy, that solved it. There was a problem in the linking of the app.js file at the bottom of my blade file. after I solved that, then it was showing a error where the div id naming was incorrect, solved that and it's working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved. There was a issue in the linking of the app.js file in my blade file. And also after the linking, because of the linking the console was showing the actual error which was a id naming error,  now it is working properly. Thanks to buddy @lindacom for pointing it out in the comment